# Getting diagonal of a matrix in numpy and excluding an element

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get the diagonal elements of a matrix, excluding one diagonal element. If I want the full diagonal elements, I know I can simply do `A.numpy.diagonal()` where `A` is a numpy square matrix to get the full array of diagonal elements. But I don't want `A[i][i]` for some `i`. So obviously I can delete the element corresponding to `i` from the output of `A.numpy.diagonal()`. But I think this is slower than using slicing? How would one use slicing on this problem to get all the diagonal elements excluding the component at `A[i][i]`?

Comment: By Slicing do you mean creating a subset array from the output of `A.numpy.diagonal()` ?

Comment: No. I mean slicing the original matrix `A` for the diagonal elements except for the one at `A[i][i`.]

Comment: A diagonal is essentially `idx = np.arange(n); A[idx, idx]`. in other words, advanced indexing with 2 identical arrays.  (A diagonal is not fast `view`.) So you could remove `i` from `idx`, and then index.

Comment: Would I remove `i` using `np.delete()`?

Comment: After a bit of testing I find it's a bit faster to first take the diagonal, and then use `np.delete` (or equivalent) to remove the ith item from the resulting 1d array.

Comment: Ah okay. You just answered my question that I posed in the comment to the answer. What did you compare `np.delete` against?

Comment: Oh sorry. I misunderstood what you said. I thought you meant deleting `i` from the diagonal indices. You actually mean deleting the `A[i][i]` from the output of `A.numpy.diagonal()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the same behavior as `diagonal` by just using `arange` for rows and columns.  Remove the index you aren't interested in before indexing (as @hpaulj noted in the comments, practically it's faster just to find the diagonal and remove the index afterwards):

---

***Setup***

```
a = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
i = 3     # exclude the diagonal element at index 3
```

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

---

```
d = np.arange(a.shape[0])
m = np.delete(d, i)

a[m, m]
```

```
array([ 0,  6, 12, 24])
```

Comment: Is there an efficient to actually just create `m` without using `np.delete()`? I always try to avoid deleting elements from static/dynamic arrays. The only other thing I can think of is just concatenating `np.arange(i)` with `np.arange(i+1,a.shape[0])`, but this is probably less efficient than using the `np.delete()`.

Comment: Honestly problably just better to delete from the result of the diagonal, but this is just to show how you'd avoid indexing a certain element

Comment: @Iamanon It is indeed faster to avoid `delete` for example by doing `m = np.arange(len(a)-1)`; `m[i:] += 1`.